# Android studio 2.2 preview 2 somewhat complecate

Tags: android, android-manifest, build-error, android-studio-2.2

I am suffering from some problem with upgrading android studio 2.2 preview 2

I made my app in android studio 1.5.0 ...now i update studio to 2.2 preview and load my project...there was various changes which i had done successfully except that rendering problem of layout.xml file.

other issue is in AndroidManifest.xml file..once i change it i never correct it .. . i want to change user permission in manifest but i cant. after editing manifest file when i rebuild it...it synchronize from somewhere and getting old code.. . now i m stuck with it...

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <!-- The following two permissions are required for location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.ACCESS_WIMAX_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.CHANGE_WIMAX_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
 <!-- Permissions required for GCM -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.GlobalClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/freedom"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Start"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.SplashScreen"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.SignUp"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Trip"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Ambassador"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Vouchers"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.MyProfile"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.EditProfile"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.VouchersDetails"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Vouchers"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.TripdetailsNew"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Trip"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.WebviewMap"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.TripdetailsNew"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.ContactUs"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.LocationMap"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.WebviewInfo"
            android:label=""
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="838269f6126086432c456c58e4cb1548f439aa5d" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.CropImage"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.ViewNotes"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.AddTripNote"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.AddExpense"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.Expense"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.WebviewPayment"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.PreviewActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppInvite.Preview" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ACTION_PREVIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!--
Service handling Google Sign-In user revocation. For apps that do not integrate with
            Google Sign-In, this service will never be started.
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo.google_measurement_service"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Gradle.build Message view**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers136Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta114Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics255Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore238Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubJorgecastilloprzPagedheadlistview101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric1310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
Warning:F:\Working Projects\ajay\FreedomTourismDemo\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-79 Warning:
    Element uses-permission#android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE at AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-79 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:12:5-79
F:\Working Projects\ajay\FreedomTourismDemo\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-79 Warning:
    Element uses-permission#android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE at AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-79 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:12:5-79
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugResources
F:\Working Projects\ajay\FreedomTourismDemo\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(52) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(53) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(54) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(55) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(57) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(58) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(59) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(60) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(61) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(62) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(63) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(64) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(65) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(66) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(67) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(68) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(76) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(77) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(78) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(79) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:(80) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\cuesoft.in\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 22.152 secs
Information:22 errors
Information:1 warning
Information:See complete output in console
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cuesoft_02.freedomtourismdemo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.7.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    /* compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.10.3@aar') {
                    transitive = true;
                }*/
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.jorgecastilloprz:pagedheadlistview:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
}
```

can anybody help???

EDIT:

one more change is that new gradle having alpha-effect by default.. how we can remove it??

Comment: Are you editing the manifest in the `gen/` folder?

Comment: where i can find that folder??

Answer (score 0):

Some uses-permission tags have invalid spaces in the string after the `android:name` tag eg 
    `<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.ACCESS_WIMAX_STATE" />`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.ACCESS_WIMAX_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.CHANGE_WIMAX_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

here i have removed the spaces:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIMAX_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIMAX_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```